# how to swap image on click?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

i wnt to swap image on click,bt here if m clicking from down image to up but again its not coming on down image if m clicking on that image...
m geting some error-**x.attr("src") is undefined**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#sortdivlink').click(function () {

        var x = $("img[src$='../Images/Sort_down.png'][name='stCodeDSC']");

        if (x.attr("SRC") == "../Images/Sort_down.png") {
            x.attr('src', x.attr('src').replace("../Images/Sort_down.png", "../Images/sort_up.png"));
        }
        else {
             x.attr('src',  x.attr('src').replace("../Images/sort_up.png", "../Images/Sort_down.png"));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you show some markup please?

Comment: what is the $ doing in the selector? "img[src$='../Images/Sort_down.png'][name='stCodeDSC']

Comment: @Timmerz its the 'attribute ends with' selector: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use a `<div>` with a css class with a `background-image` and dimensions, and use $(div).toggleClass("new-image") to use the updated `background-image`

that will greatly simplify your code.

[EDIT]

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style>
    .first-image
    {
       background-image: url( 'http://www.google.com/press/zeitgeist2001/google_logo.gif' );
       width:218px;
       height:90px;
       background-position:center;
       background-repeat:no-repeat;
    }

    .second-image
    {
       background-image: url( 'http://www.google.com/doodle4google/2008/images/regional_doodles/CO-80106-16a267f8-3.jpg' );
       width:350px;
       height:224px;
       background-position:center;
       background-repeat:no-repeat;
    }
    </style>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function( ) 
    { 
        $("#target-div").click( function( ) 
        {  
           $("#target-div").toggleClass("second-image");
        });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="target-div" class="first-image"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: do u hav any sample for this//

Answer (score 8):

I would imagine this is due to the selector you're using to assign `x`, which is likely returning null. I would consider maybe adding an Id or CSS class to the image, and then simplifying the selector to something like this:

```
var x = $('img.sortDirectionImage');
```

Alternatively, if you know that the `sortdivlink` element, will only have a single image, you could simply search for an `img` element within the context of that element, for example:

```
// within the click function scope
var x = $('img', this);
```

**Edit**

Additionally, I would recommend using more recognisable variable names; you might know what `x` is, but the next person that comes to read your code might not.

Comment: This will also resolve the issue with finding an image by its src and then changing the src, therefore no longer finding it.

Answer (score 1):

Look at my script I wrote long time ago (without any jQuery):

```
function changeImg(element) {
        var img = document.getElementById(element);
        if (img.src == "../images/expand.png") {
            // collapse
            img.src = "../images/collapse.png";
        }
        else {
            // expand
            img.src = "../images/expand.png";
        }
    }
```

Normal HTML-Markup:

```
<span onclick="changeImg('ansprechpartner');return false;">...</span>
```

Maybe it will work for you...