# how to swap image on clicking on image?

Tags: javascript

Here I use two images. when i click once on the Sort_down.png image then it changes to Sort_up.png. 
When I click on this image again it is not changing back to Sort_down.png, how can I achieve this ?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
function clkimg() {
        var img = document.getElementById('stCodeDSC');
                img.src = '../Images/sort_up.png';

        }
  </script>


    <td width="11%" bgcolor="#C5DEFF" class="menu_header">
    <div align="center" onclick="clkimg();" > 
    <img name="stCodeDSC"  class="img" src="../Images/Sort_down.png"  id="stCodeDSC">
  </div>
 </td>
```

Comment: You are not changing image source from sort_up to source_down on second click event.

Comment: ya i dnt hv ny idea ,,cn u plz tll..

Comment: this looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10090562/how-to-swap-image-on-click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't telling it to sort down. In your click code you'll need to test if the image is showing up or down and change it accordingly. Something like:

```
if(img.src === '../Images/sort_up.png')
    img.src = '../Images/sort_down.png';
else
    img.src = '../Images/sort_up.png';
```

Generally, however, this would be better handled by adding or removing a class on click and styling the class using css.

Comment: its changing only once...again its nt changing on down

Comment: @SHAURAJSINGH: it should work. Check your images exist on the path. Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/xc8Pe/

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the browser you're using, when the source of an image is set to a relative URL, reading it back will give you the absolute URL. If you want to use a toggle, you can check for a string in the source, for example:

```
function clkimg() {
  var img = document.getElementById('stCodeDSC'),
      nextImg = img.src.indexOf('up.png')>0 ? 'down':'up';
  img.src = '../Images/sort_' + nextImg + '.png';
}
```

If the sort_up and sort_down images are actually icons just identifying the up or down state of the current sort, you can combine the two images into one and use them as a sprite that you display using CSS. More details will be available at https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=css+sprite